# Block specific User Agent in ISAPI REWRITE 3.0

Tags: url-rewriting, user-agent, isapi

I really can't find a solution, can someone pleas tell me how to block the following specific user agent exactly via `isapi rewrite 3.0`?

I want to block:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/28.0

Current solution, but doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} ^Mozilla/5.0\ (Windows\ NT\ 6.1;\ WOW64;\ rv:28.0)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/28.0 [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

I tried so many ways but it doesn't seem to work...

Please help!

Comment: That's the user-agent i want to block with Helicon's Isapi Rewrite 3.0: 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0

That's my last solution:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} Mozilla/5.0\ (Windows\ NT\ 6.1;\ WOW64;\ rv:28.0)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/28.0 [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]

But the user-agent isn't blocked... it can only depend on some syntax errors

Comment: Thank you! ... but yes I have... I got that site about 5 times today while trying to find a solution... maybe there is a problem with the blanks or something else...?

Comment: done... which other information do you need?

Comment: Logically, you should explain what happens when someone with that User Agent goes to the site currently, and what do you want to happen.

Comment: What happens: nothing. the RewriteCondition doesnt work
What i want to happen: Clients with that User-Agents should be blocked. RADICALLY :)  (RewriteRule .? -[F]) 

that's all i want. No redirection. Just blocking.

Helicon's Isapi Rewrite works fine for me with other rules about url-rewriting..., but I'am driving insane cause I know there must only be a tiny syntax mistake in my command...

Let me ask my question more exactly: I want the condition to return true for that useragent but it doesn't work. Where is the error?

Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: try escaping the brackets in the UA string.. `\(` and `\)`

Comment: done... i'll let you know if this works
thank you so much!

Comment: Problem solved: msturdy - you are my hero! So easy but hard enough for blind rewrite noobs like me :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `(` and `)` characters in your UA string:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} ^Mozilla/5.0\ \(Windows\ NT\ 6.1;\ WOW64;\ rv:28.0\)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/28.0 [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```

`(` and `)` are [special characters in Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards)